# set source ip for remote rsyslog

Tags: logging, remote-server, syslog, rsyslog

I am using rsyslog-8.22 on my product. Is there a way for me to set the source ip when forwarding a message to a remote server ? 
I need this since the remote server is running a firewall which is opened to a specific interface, I'd like to be able to specify this IF when forwarding messages.
Thanks, 
Ran

Comment: IMHO, that's something controlled by your routing table, not by rsyslog. Look at [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/182550/specifing-ip-address-for-outbound-connections-on-a-multi-ip-host).

Comment: Solved using spoof model of rsyslog